# How can i distinguished request actions in a serializer DRF Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

```
class EmailSerializerU(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    customlink = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['id','owner','address','type','primary','customlink']

    def get_customlink(self, instance):
        #Here Logic IF Action=List then A)    IF Action=GET  THEN b)
        req=self.context['request']
        full_url = ''.join(['http://', get_current_site(req).domain])+'/emails'
        return full_url
```

In the def_get_customlink function i am trying to set the full_url depending on the action of the URL/API. How can i access this value? Is the context/the request somehow available?

1. tried self.action, didnt work.
   `self.action` leads to `EmailSerializer` object has no attribute `action`
2. tried `req=self.context['request']`, yet it shows an url not an action

output for single get
`<rest_framework.request.Request: GET '/emails/17/'>`

output for list
`<rest_framework.request.Request: GET '/emails/'>`

Any advice if a custom serializer is a good way to create custom links so that the generic output shows links to each other?

Comment: You can do it if you include it in the model or write your own custom serializer. In Django, business logic should go to the views layer. not in the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve it. To have dynamic links during the serialization that are different with the action of the called url.

1. in urls.py pass a new var actionc

   ```
    path('emails/<int:pk>/', ERetrieveUpdateDeleteItem.as_view(actionc='detail') ,name='email-detail'),
   ```
2. in views.py define actionc an attribute of the class

   ```
    class ERetrieveUpdateDeleteItem(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        serializer_class = EmailSerializerU
        queryset = Email.objects.all()
        permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
        actionc = None
   ```
3. In views.py pass actionc to the serializer context

   ```
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super(ERetrieveUpdateDeleteItem, self).get_serializer_context()
        print(self.request.GET.urlencode())
        context.update({"actionc": self.actionc})
        return context
   ```
4. There is a function to_representation in serializers. use it to
   add extra content, in this case a dynamic link

   ```
    class EmailSerializerU(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['id','owner','address','type','primary']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
            req=self.context['request']
            actionc=self.context['actionc']
            representation = super().to_representation(instance)
            if actionc=='detail':
                full_url = ''.join(['http://', get_current_site(req).domain])+'/emails'
                representation['customlink'] = full_url
            else:
                full_url = ''.join(['http://', get_current_site(req).domain])+instance.get_absolute_url()
                representation['customlink'] = full_url
            return representation
   ```

Result action list example. json objects that include a link to the detail view.

```
    {
    "count": 11,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/emails/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
        "id": 5,
        "owner": 1,
        "address": "sdsd@kkk.lop",
        "type": "work",
        "primary": true,
        "customlink": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/emails/5/"
        },
        {
        "id": 7,
        "owner": 3,
        "address": "sdsd@kkksd.lopsd",
        "type": "home",
        "primary": true,
        "customlink": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/emails/7/"
        }
    }
```